# Calculate a bunch of data to display on stacked bar

Tags: spss

I'm struggeling with creating my first chart.

i have a dataset of ordinal scaled data from a survey.
There i have several question with the possible answer from 1 - 5.
So have around 110 answers from different persons which i want to collect and show in a stacked bar.
Those data looks like:

```
| taste | region | brand | price |
|   1   |    3   |   4   |   2   |
|   1   |    1   |   5   |   1   |
|   1   |    3   |   4   |   3   |
|   2   |    2   |   5   |   1   |
|   1   |    1   |   4   |   5   |
|   5   |    3   |   5   |   2   |
|   1   |    5   |   5   |   2   |
|   2   |    4   |   1   |   3   |
|   1   |    3   |   5   |   4   |
|   1   |    4   |   4   |   5   |
...
```

to can display that in a stacked bar chart, i need to sum that.
so i know at the end it need to be calculated like:

```
|       | taste  | region | brand  | price  |
|   1   |   60   |   20   |   32   |   12   |
|   2   |    23  |   32   |   54   |   22   |
|   3   |    24  |   66   |   36   |   65   |
|   4   |    55  |   68   |   28   |   54   |
|   5   |    10  |   10   |   12   |   22   |
```

(this is just to demonstarte, the values are not correct)

Or somehow there is already a function for it on spss but i have now idea where an how.

Any advice how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a single command but there are many ways to get to where you want. Here's one:

first recreating your sample data:

```
data list list/ taste region brand price .
begin data
 1 3 4 2 
 1 1 5 1 
 1 3 4 3 
 2 2 5 1 
 1 1 4 5 
 5 3 5 2 
 1 5 5 2 
 2 4 1 3 
 1 3 5 4 
 1 4 4 5 
end data.
```

Now counting the values for each row:

```
vector t(5) r(5) b(5) p(5).
* the vector command is only nescessary so the new variables will be ordered compfortably for the following parts.
do repeat vl= 1 to 5/t=t1 to t5/r=r1 to r5/b=b1 to b5/p=p1 to p5.
  compute t=(taste=vl).
  compute r=(region=vl).
  compute b=(brand=vl).
  compute p=(price=vl).
end repeat.
```

Now we can aggregate and restructure to arrive to the the exact data structure you specified:

```
aggregate /outfile=* /break= /t1 to t5 r1 to r5 b1 to b5 p1 to p5 = sum(t1 to p5).
varstocases /make taste from t1 to t5 /make region from r1 to r5 
            /make brand from b1 to b5/ make price from p1 to p5/index=val(taste).
compute val = char.substr(val,2,1).
alter type val(f1).
```